# UISearchBar + Search Display Bar in an UITableView within a UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

In my iOS app I have the following :

- Navigation Controller
- Some other controller
- UITabBarController

  - UITableView

    - UISearchBar + UISearchDisplayController

The behaviour I would expect to have is the search bar would move to the navigation bar when focused.

Instead currently it stays where it is : at the top of the table view.

I tried the same view without the TabBarController and the search works as expected : it moves to the navigation bar on focus.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Where did the navigation bar come from? There is not navigation controller in your description.

Comment: Yes, missed that, I have a navigation controller link to another controller which has a segues to my UITabBarController